# How to make PRE expand to column size while not increase with new data

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, pre

I have a card (1) containing two other cards (2 and 3) using bootstrap columns. The card number 2 has some selects and other elements and changes its height according to the screen. The card number 3 has a pre element and some buttons. What I'm trying to acheive is to make the height of both columns, each containing one card, the same. The pre element will be receiving new data dynamically, so I want it to have scroll bars to keep the data readable. 
I was able to do that by specifying a height to the card:

```
height: 10rem; overflow: auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

However I need it to expand accordingly to the card 1 size, that works if I set the height to 100%.So I want it to display like when height is set to 100%, but to work like when height is set to a specific value.
Is that possible?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="mt-1" id="comcard">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i> CARD
          </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#comcard">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-header">
                CARD 2
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select1" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select1">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select2" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select2">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select3" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select3">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select4" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select4">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-header"> CARD 3 </div>
              <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="card" style="height: 100%; overflow: auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;">
                  <div class="card-body" id="terminal_div">
                    <pre id="terminal_pre"></pre>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <fieldset id="group_io">
                  <div class="input-group mt-2">
                    <select class="custom-select col-sm-2" id="io_select">
                      <option value="0" selected>1</option>
                      <option value="1">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">Send</button>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Clear</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Pre with height set to 100% (Keeps expanding forever with new data):

https://jsfiddle.net/Fperola/kL17ewpv/17/

Pre with height set to a value (e.g. 10rem) (Adds the scroll bars as needed but is not responsive to different screens):

https://jsfiddle.net/Fperola/kL17ewpv/16/

Comment: can you share the screenshot of which issue do you face with more data in the pre (card3) and share what will be your expected outcome

Comment: @AkberIqbal I Just added to the question examples of the two different scenarios. The outcome I want is for it to look like when the height is set to 100% without any content and as new data is added the pre size remains fixed and the scrollbar will make the data still accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it was possible by pure CSS, had to put in jQuery... A few things that I did:

- assign id `card2` & `card3` & a class `ourClass` to make things simple
- changed your inline style to `overflow-y: scroll; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;`
- added some jQuery to read the results from the `#card2` and set `#card3` accordingly

**working code snippet** below (please run it in full page to see the effects):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('#terminal_pre').append("123");
  $('#terminal_pre').append("&#10;");
}, 1000);

function setRelevantHeight() {
  var newHeight = $("#card2").height();
  $('#heightHere').text($("#card2").height());
  $("#card3").height(newHeight);
  var newAdjustedHeight = newHeight - 175;
  //console.log("newAdjustedHeight:",newAdjustedHeight);
  $(".ourClass").height(newAdjustedHeight);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setRelevantHeight();
})

$(window).resize(function() {
  setRelevantHeight()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div class="mt-1" id="comcard">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i> CARD
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#comcard">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div id='card2' class="col-sm col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-header">
                CARD 2
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select1" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select1">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select2" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select2">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select3" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select3">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <form>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Select4" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select class="form-control" id="Select4">
                        <option selected value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id='card3' class="col-sm col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-header"> CARD 3 </div>
              <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="card ourClass" style=" overflow-y: scroll; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;">
                  <div class="card-body" id="terminal_div">
                    <pre id="terminal_pre"></pre>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <fieldset id="group_io">
                  <div class="input-group mt-2">
                    <select class="custom-select col-sm-2" id="io_select">
                      <option value="0" selected>1</option>
                      <option value="1">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">Send</button>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Clear</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id='heightHere'> this is </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful. However, there's still two things not working exactly as I expected. One is that the 1st time that the main card is shown card 3 is not displaying corrctly, and the other is that card 3 never gets smaller, only adjusts its size to become bigger. Despite that, with your approach I made it work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Akber Iqbal's approach I made it work as intended.
I just made a few changes to it:

- Added an event call fired when the main card is shown to set the size of the cards correctly on the 1st time:

  `$('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (){
      setRelevantHeight();
   });`
- Used a fiedset containing the elements inside card 2 body to be used as a referenced to get the height of this card:

  `function setRelevantHeight() {
    let newHeight = $("#fieldsetcard2").height();
    let temp = newHeight + 91;
    $("#card3").height(temp);
    let newAdjustedHeight = newHeight - 48;
    $(".ourClass").height(newAdjustedHeight);
  }`

Here's the final code:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div class="mt-1" id="comcard">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i> CARD
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#comcard">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div id='card2' class="col-sm col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-header">
                CARD 2
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">

                 <fieldset id="fieldsetcard2">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="Select1" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Select1">
                          <option selected value="0">1</option>
                          <option value="1">2</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="Select2" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Select2">
                          <option selected value="0">1</option>
                          <option value="1">2</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="Select3" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Select3">
                          <option selected value="0">1</option>
                          <option value="1">2</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="Select4" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"> ABCDEFGHIJKL: </label>
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Select4">
                          <option selected value="0">1</option>
                          <option value="1">2</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </fieldset>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id='card3' class="col-sm col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-header"> CARD 3 </div>
              <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <div id="temp_id" class="card ourClass" style="overflow-y: scroll; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;">
                  <div class="card-body " id="terminal_div">
                    <pre id="terminal_pre"></pre>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <fieldset id="group_io">
                  <div class="input-group mt-2">
                    <select class="custom-select col-sm-2" id="io_select">
                      <option value="0" selected>1</option>
                      <option value="1">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">Send</button>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Clear</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Fperola/jLyqa4rs/51/